# Can chanting certain mantras and reading stories rid us of mahapatak/maha papam (great sins)?

Tags: mantras, sin

We often say that there is no remedy for Mahapapam/Panch pahapapam, but the Ramraksha Stotra and Shree Ganesh Atharvasheersha both very clearly mention that reciting them would help us get rid of the sins.

Following is the excerpt :-

Rama Raksha Stotram, right at the start mentions (Translation from [Hindupedia](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Rama_Raksha_Stotram) -

> Charitam Raghunathasya , shata koti pravistaram
>   Ekaikam aksharam punsam, mahapataka nashanam
>
> The story of Rama is written in four billions words,
>   **But reading even one letter of that**, destroys all great sins.

Similarly Shree Ganesh Atharvasheersha mentions Translation from [greenmesg.org](http://greenmesg.org/stotras/ganesha/ganapati_atharvashirsha.php)–

> Etadarvasheerha yodhite, sa brahma bhuyaye kalpate,
>   Sa sarvatah sukhmedhate, sa panch maha papat pramuchayate
>
> He who studies this Atharvashirsha (with Shraddha), will become fit to realize Brahman,
>   He will not be (permanently) tied down by any obstacles (and his consciousness will become clearer), 
>   (Permanent) Happiness will increase within his consciousness, wherever he is (i.e. at all times),
>   **He will get freed from the five grave Sins** (the memory of sins tend to create permanent obstacles within the consciousness for the jivas to sense the Paramatman),

So if one has indulged in a maha pataka, can reciting these mantras or reading and listening to the stories help get rid of the sin?

Comment: See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19646/4732 ... But one has to be qualified to chant a Mantra.. The Mantra has to be made Siddha by Purascharana first.. so there are conditions attached..