# karma vs. Divine Grace

Tags: vishnu

A person may get some suffering due to his past karma. However, if he prays to God for his protection, he may be protected from the same suffering. Does this mean prayer has the power to eradicate past karma?

Comment: Does this mean prayer has the power to eradicate past karma? - This is already asked here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19644/does-prayer-remove-bad-deeds-of-past-lives/19646

Comment: @Rickross So not a duplicate?