# How are pujas able to negate effect of Grahas and Nakshatras given in kundali?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, nakshatra

Different pujas are prescribed for different things. For example, I have Gandamool nakshatra(jyestha) so pooja is prescribed but how can a mere pooja do anything to something that was prescribed at birth.

Comment: Doshas shown in our horoscopes are nothing but reflections of bad karmas from previous lives. The appropriate pujas can thus clear those bad karmas.

Comment: Pujas can clear sins from past lives --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19646/4732

Comment: Yet another relevant answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48085/4732

Comment: @Rickross so when people say this puja is to 'pacify' some particular graha, are they wrong?

Comment: No they are not wrong .. certain bad karmas make certain Grahas rude to us .. then we need to appease/pacify them with certain rituals or pujas.

Comment: @Rambhakt you can watch Shri PVR Narasimha Rao Ji explanation on yt(afaik its a talk delivered by him on the infinity foundation channel)for how remedial measures for certain placement of grahas work ....